# How can I pull all named HTML tags into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with data I need to parse in the format of

```
<tag>dataIwant</tag>
<tag>dataIwant</tag>
<tag>dataIwant</tag>
<othertag>moarData</othertag>
<othertag>moarData</othertag>
```

For simplicity, I'd like to extract all sets of any named tag as an array (preferably just the values). For example:

```
array1(dataIwant,dataIwant,dataIwant);
array2(moarData,moarData);
```

It's easy to extract this with jQuery IF they were named elements or had classes, but they don't. All I have is custom tagnames up to 20 or more in a row with the same name. If I can convert them to array, it will simplify my work with them. I could certainly write my own function to parse the information, but isn't there an easier way to do this?

Alternate suggestions welcome so long as I can reach the data and retain the order in which it was read (the tags represent data locations on a form I need to fill so order matters).

Comment: So these are custom HTML Elements? Do you know what the elements are before? Where do they live? Real world example would make this easy to answer.

Comment: Is the data valid XML by any chance? Or is it just plaintext? Depending on what the data is, the answers can be very simple or very complicated. Does the file have headers for example? Eg, is there a data row that states that the two tags used are `tag` and `othertag` ?

Comment: I believe it's valid XML though when I tried to parse it as such it gave me a bad data error. I thought it would be easier to run a command against the string to pull out all of X tag as array, then Y tag, then Z. I already know the names of the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an .each() method to gather all the text from each custom tag into an array.

Also, you can use document.querySelectorAll to get a list that you can then iterate over. This would then require more work since it would also include the tag in the array though.

Note that I have added a style rule to get all to display in separate lines.

```js
var tagArr = [];

$('tag').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  tagArr.push(text);
})
console.log(tagArr); // gives ["dataIwant","dataIwant","dataIwant"]

var otherTagArr = [];

$('otherTag').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  otherTagArr.push(text);
})
console.log(otherTagArr); //gives gives "moarData","moarData"]
```

```css
tag,otherTag {display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tag>dataIwant</tag>
<tag>dataIwant</tag>
<tag>dataIwant</tag>
<othertag>moarData</othertag>
<othertag>moarData</othertag>
```

Comment: I have the data in a string so technically I did $(strpage).find('tagname').each, but that worked well. It's simple and repeatable so I'm marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a common parent and you do not know what the tag names are you are after, you can look over the children and push them into an object or arrays using the tag name.

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var set = Array.from(wrapper.children).reduce( function(o, el){
 o[el.tagName] = o[el.tagName] || [];
 o[el.tagName].push(el.textContent)
 return o
}, {});
console.log(set)
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <tag>dataIwant</tag>
  <tag>dataIwant</tag>
  <tag>dataIwant</tag>
  <othertag>moarData</othertag>
  <othertag>moarData</othertag>
</div>
```